# Edit Customer Address Form's Name Fields

Tags: magento-1.7, address, form-key

I am editing the layout of my edit.phtml in template/customer/address/, i have edited the layout and labels of some fields there, no problem.

Except, i have 3 fields in the code which i can't edit because they are being called on the following way:

```
Begin of the code:
$this->getBlockHtml('formkey') in address magento
Later in the code:
<?php echo $this->getNameBlockHtml() ?>
```

I have no idea where to edit the layout/label names, etc. of this fields.
All evening i tried to find out where to do, but searching other questions is leading me to .php files, but not, for example to the  tag of the field.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->getBlockHtml('formkey')` creates a hidden field which you should not remove. (It is a security feature to help protect against cross-site scripting attacks.)

`<?php echo $this->getNameBlockHtml() ?>` would logically take you to `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Block\Address\Edit.php` which is probably the PHP file you mentioned. The important thing to note there is the `getNameBlockHtml()` method, which dynamically creates a new `'customer/widget_name'` block. As the name of the block suggests, the template for that block can be found in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\widget\name.phtml`

Comment: Thank you Tyler, that did the trick. name.phtml did contain the code i needed.